# How to attract practitioners of DevOps as mature member candidates to bring their expertise to our DevOps SE site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In a related DevOps SE Meta discussion, @Bruce Becker suggested:

> .. we might not have enough mature members yet to handle a lot more
>   traffic, .. [] I do have the impression that practitioners of DevOps
>   would rather expound on their blog or podcast, rather than come here
>   and help build community by answering questions and curating content.

Can we do anything about this? Do you think many practitioners might be not aware of our site, or do not see a benefit for them in it? Could we do something about that - like asking those we know personally who might be a good match for the Q&A format and sharing knowledge to join?

Other ideas?

I hear very often the argument that the site should grow organically which I generally agree, but I do not how exactly this works. I'll ask another question because I do not like the attitude (might be my personal misinterpretation) variant "organical growth => black box process => nothing to do about it => wait".

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about promotional ideas, then integration with other forums may be helpful.  For example, tweeting out "good" questiosn and answers on a periodic basis might draw some eyes to the site.

Answer (score 0):

SO has [23 tags containing "devops"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/) in their names.

SF has [4 tags containing "devops"](https://serverfault.com/tags/) in their names.

Could there a banner/infobox be implemented at each of the according questions' pages that gives a hint/link to DO?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two post where I suggest a solution

1. [Adapting privileges for low site activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380013/adapting-privileges-for-low-site-activity)
2. [It is in the best interests of all sites for StackExchange to have a more hands-on approach to topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380152/it-is-in-the-best-interests-of-all-sites-for-stackexchange-to-have-a-more-hands?noredirect=1#comment1268274_380152)